# How to reset variable value using reset button in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk, reset

I need to reset a Lua variable score value, using a reset button: Please check the code:

```
 local result = display.newText( score, 670, tabelaFundo5.y,native.systemFontBold,35 )
 resultadoFutebol:setFillColor( 0,0,0 )
```

Here the variable `score` have a dynamic value, it prints fine, but I need to reset this value when I shall click a RESET button. I am working on corona SDK and Lua.

Comment: What's the question here? Where's your `reset` button? What does clicking it do? Where is your `scope` variable defined? How does that scope relate to the `reset` button and its callback function? Have you tried anything for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't detailed enough. But You could just create simple button.

local button = display.newRect(300,300, 100,100)

```
local function onObjectTouch( event )
if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
    score = 0
    result.text = tostring(score)
end
return true
end
button:addEventListener( "touch", onObjectTouch )
```